# Creating an app that has more an one button to go to the next activity

Tags: android

I have a question. How can I put two or more buttons on the MainActivity and have it go to the SecondActivity? All the SecondActivities are going to be different.

Comment: I have a question: Did you even bother googling for any tutorial?

Comment: Yes I did but every time I googled it I came up with something different. Also not what I wanted either

Comment: I guess you have to improve your Google-Fu

Comment: I guess I will it's getting to know more of the main source code like in other programs like case statements and things that they start teaching in school

Comment: Unfortunately for you, this is not a tutorial site. Nor a teaching one, in a narrow sense.

Comment: Yeah I kinda got that feeling

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop a button using android studio. once the button had been placed within the layout. In properties palette you will be able to find something called onClick. which means the action to be performed once the button click occurs, give a name for the onClick method eg: add

`public void add (View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,displayActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}`

displayActivity is the name of your second Activity. once the button had been clicked you will be directed to the secondActivity.The same step can be followed for the next button.

Comment: Ok I will try that thanks. Now how do make another button work when there are two buttons on the MainActivity?